# Android phone not dumping stack trace

Tags: java, android, stack-trace

I have a problem with my phone not printing uncaught exceptions in logcat.

To show the problem i have this piece of code:

```
ArrayList list = null;
list.add("something");
```

The only thing logcat shows is:

```
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4160ac80)
```

The weird thing is that i have another phone which prints the correct null pointer exception. Furthermore, printing messages with Log.e(TAG,"error") works perfectly. Anyone know why this might happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked if anyone has the same problem:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Uncaught exceptions are handled by `Thread.defaultUncaughtHandler`. Depending on the platform and manufacturer this might differ.

Comment: It used to work, but stopped a week ago for some reason. I did install some apps which require root access. Maybe they broke something.

Comment: Yes, root apps might be able to interfere with uncaughtHandlers.

Comment: Surround with try/catch and use exception.printstacktrace